# How to use backnavigation icon in ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

In my App call demo extends `ListActivity` and I want to use back button navigation icon . Please suggest me how could be possible
example:   `public class demo extends ListActivity` and I don't want to change `ListActivity` to extends another activity

Comment: I believe you're looking for the [`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) method of `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

write this line:

```
 assert getActionBar() != null;
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in ListActivity `getSupportActionBar` is not supported. so you should use `Actionbar`

or you can use delegate method for that like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppCompatCallback callback = new AppCompatCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    AppCompatDelegate delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, callback);

    delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate.setContentView(R.layout.saved_report_activity);

    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    delegate.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(SomeActivity.this);
        }
    });
```

and make sure that your AppCompatCallback import v7 lib.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatCallback;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
```

best approach is use `Delegate for ListActivity`.

Comment: I used your code but getting null pointer exception , I uesd getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); and  AppCompatDelegate delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, callback);code is not running in my app

Comment: wait i m updating my answer a little